# Criteria a function has to follow in order for there to exist an n such that the function's nth derivative is itself

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, relations

Is there some property that all functions that meet the following condition satisfy?

$\exists n$ s.t $\frac{d^nf}{{dx}^n} = f(x)$

So far I have tried using the Taylor series, which yields a rather unwieldy recurrence relation in terms of the coefficients of the Taylor polynomial. I have not yet learned how to solve differential equations or the Fourier Series so I wasn't able to think of any other techniques to solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple homogenous linear ordinary differential equation and its characteristic equation.

$$
\begin{align}\\
0&=\frac{d^{n}f}{dx^{n}}-f\\
\\
0&=\lambda^{n}-\lambda
\end{align}
$$

The solution is in the following form:

$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{C_{i}e^{\lambda_{i}x}}
$$

The $\lambda_{i}$s are the $n$-th roots of unity

Comment: I have never seen this technique before. Can you expand or provide links on where the characteristic equation comes from and why this technique works?

Comment: This is the first technique you will learn to solve ODEs. I recommend you to read any source about the topic and you will encounter this.